# jquery DatePicker changing minDate option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jquery DatePicker. I have a dropdown and I need to reset the minDate option of DatePicker based from the dropdown. Here's the code snippet.

HTML

```
<input id="Date_From" name="Date_From">
<select id="Select" >
  <option value="Choice1">Choice1</option>
  <option value="Choice2">Choice2</option>
<select>
```

JS

```
  $("#Date_From").datepicker();
     $("#Date_To").datepicker();

  $('#Select').change(function () {
      var option = this.value;

      if (option == 'Choice1') 
      {
          $( "#Date_From" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2015, 1 - 1, 1) );
      }
      else if (option == 'Choice2') 
      {
          $( "#Date_From" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2015, 1 - 7, 1) );
      }
      else{
      }
    });
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: DatePicker wont change the minDate based from dropdown

Comment: `1 - 7`? should be `7 - 1`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gneygqhx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the month calculation, you need to pass `7-1`(6) for `01 Jul 2015`

```js
$("#Date_From").datepicker();
$("#Date_To").datepicker();

$('#Select').change(function() {
  var option = this.value;
  if (option == 'Choice1') {
    $("#Date_From").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(2015, 1 - 1, 1));
  } else if (option == 'Choice2') {
    $("#Date_From").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(2015, 7 - 1, 1));
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="Date_From" name="Date_From" />
<select id="Select">
  <option value="Choice1">Choice1</option>
  <option value="Choice2">Choice2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked on the jsfiddle. I just need to implement it on my code.